What are magic methods tied to type str?
Ok so I am trying to learn Python. I notice that -
string = 100
type(string)
<class 'int'>
dir(string)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__ceil__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__
                                                                                                     │divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__float__', '__floor__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '_
                                                                                                     │_getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__index__', '__init__', '
                                                                                                     │__init_subclass__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lshift__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__',
                                                                                                     │ '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdivmod_
                                                                                                     │_', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__
                                                                                                     │', '__ror__', '__round__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__r
                                                                                                     │xor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__tru
                                                                                                     │nc__', '__xor__', 'as_integer_ratio', 'bit_count', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'from_b
                                                                                                     │ytes', 'imag', 'is_integer', 'numerator', 'real', 'to_bytes']

That what I'm trying to understand is what are all those magic methods? I think I halfway understand that an integer attribute is subject to object oriented programming, but is there anything else?

You are introspecting an int object, not a str,  although you assign it to a variable named string. you need to learn to walk before you run.

Being referred to by an attribute is irrelevant.  Everything in Python is an object, i.e. they are instances of a class (a type) including ints and strings, and even classes themselves (also functions).

(Nearly) all magic methods are documented at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html.
